# JUnit Parameterized with big number of tests

Tags: java, junit

I have json file with input data end expected results. I use junit and RunWith(Prametrized.class). There are more than 1000 of (input, expected_result) pairs and after 140-150 test there is no free RAM(my machine has 32Gb ram). Is there any way to solve this problem? Like to start every test in separate process or something else...

Comment: The amount of RAM you have is secondary. You probably have to increase the max. heap size of the VM running your unit tests.

Comment: @Ralf I set it to 16 Gb and it did not help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I resolved my problem just adding System.gc() in tearDown method. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for `Parameterized` states the following:

> When running a parameterized test class, instances are created for the cross-product of the test methods and the test data elements.

For each of those instances JUnit will keep track of your test results **and** your input parameters, which will be held in memory until the whole test finishes.

You can try to minimize the memory footprint, by combining multiple tests into one or by reducing your test data, but since you're getting an OOM after only a few tests it is probably best to think about an other way to load your test data (e.g. by manually loading them from the filesystem and processing them in a loop).

But keep in mind that you should keep your (unit) tests as small and simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

1000 looks like a lot of parameters for a single test case. Are you sure that you need all of them?

IMHO, you should have some data for the normal case, and for boundaries. Either you are trying to "over cover" your code, or maybe you have many boundaries, and in this case you should break your code into more units.

If you have a general pattern that you want to cover with many data, maybe you can try [JUnit Theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories) to generalize your test.

Hope this will help.

Comment: The thing is that data are read from external source and to avoid creating a lot of test classes manually, I need to perform them in such way.